# Can you change or append a transition inside a function from a link with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, supersized

Is it possible with jQuery to change a transition inside a function with a link?

With the supersize plugin (the docs are here): 
http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/docs.html 
I'd like to change or append the transition number to show the different options.
Say if you clicked on a link **2 Slide Right**, 
it would change the transition number and run that option.
Be easier then running different slideshows if it can be done.

```
$(function(){
$.supersized({

slide_interval:5000,    
transition:1, // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
transition_speed:700,
slide_links:'blank',
slides:[
{image : '1.jpg'},
{image : '2.jpg'},  
{image : '3.jpg'},
{image : '4.jpg'}
]
});
```

Comment: You can't change the object that was passed in after it's used by the plugin, you can only do that if the plugin exposes a method to change the options while running, and to figure out if it does that, you have to read the documentation.

Comment: So once it applied by the DOM kind of thing that's it, you'd have to append it before the plugin loads. Thanks, no need to pursue that idea then.